# How to change the node stack limit for spago?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack-overflow, purescript, spago

I am working on a project in PureScript which runs lots of huge and stack-extensive tests via `spago test` feature. In most cases the recursion is so deep that I reach the limit and the tests fail with `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Normally I would just run `node` with `--stack-size=$ALOT` flag, but here I don't have direct access to the JavaScript evaluator (have I?). In a different case I would use `NODE_OPTIONS` env variable, but here it is impossible as said in the error message:

> `node: --stack-size= is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS`

Is there a way to access `node` flags in `spago` or bypass this issue in any other manner? Also, my case cannot be solved with TCO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `spago test` consists of two steps:

1. `spago build` to generate js files in `./output`
2. Run the compiled test code with node

Step two can be manually accomplished with:

`node --stack-size=40000 -e "require('./output/Test.Main/index').main()"`